# What does a Sri Lankan visa for Indians look like?

Tags: visas, sri-lanka, colombo

I applied for a Sri Lankan ETA online. I got an approval notice and PFA within a few minutes. Is this a real visa or should I wait for the real one?

Should I pin this to my passport?

Please advise.

[image: ETA Approval Notice]

Comment: You should black out your personal details

Comment: Please upload a redacted version of the document in which your personal details are hidden.

Comment: Also black out your email address! (And for the embassy)

Answer (score 7):

You don’t have to wait for any more info. **That is it.**  You can verify the status [here](https://eta.gov.lk/etaslvisa/pages/checkStatus.jsp) if you please.

**Do NOT** pin anything to your passport ever! Just print this document and carry it along.

Since you asked, here is what it looks like:

**[Sample Notice](http://www.eta.gov.lk/slvisa/visainfo/sample.jsp#7)**